# Inner pop up form shown on load in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

When I click on the "send email" link I should have a pop up with a filling form, then when I click on "send email" I have another pop up with a thanks message. This works fine on all browsers except IE8.

Here what it gaves me each time I access the page itself:

http://s17.postimg.org/4w7qapmzj/screenshot1.png

The white box (without the message) of the inner pop is loaded directly on IE8 and gives me this white blank box which is annoying.

Here is the code:

```
<section id="gravity_thanks_ar" class="lightbox hidden">
<div class="lightbox_fade"></div>
<div class="lightbox_box_inner" id="idbox_inner">
    <a href="#" class="nohistory lightbox_close lightbox_inner_close">

<div class="gravity_ar_div">
        <div id="hRecDivPopUp">
        </div>
</div>
```

```
.lightbox_box_inner {
    width: 788px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
     box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     left: 16%;
     top: 20px;
     padding: 20px;
     position: fixed;
     overflow: auto;
}

var unbindOpenThanksAr = function(){
                jQuery("#mailto .lightbox_close").unbind("click",openThanksAr);
            }
            var openThanksAr=function(evObj){
                evObj.preventDefault();
                window.LightBox.setup("gravity_thanks_ar",function(){unbindOpenThanksAr()});
                window.LightBox.open("gravity_thanks_ar");
            }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your problem could be from the use of certain css styles. Refer to this link for what is and isn't supported in IE8. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Also try if you haven't already to use <!DOCTYPE html>